# 16.10 No HPLIP avalible in the software center

Tags: printing, 16.10

I do not find the print utility HPLIP in the Ubuntu 16.10 software center.
Is it not available for 16.10?
Thanks in advance for any help.
Tot.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Where exactly it isn't available? If at the software center then it's nothing new, it happened already in the previous release. You should be able to install it with *sudo apt install hplip*.

Comment: There have been a couple of posts regarding software that does not show as available in the software center - this is one of them.  As mentioned by @CelticWarrior hplip can be installed manually, if it is not currently in your system.  `sudo apt-get install hplip`